# How do you interpret the cross product, dot product, when vectors represent things like houses?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume you have a vector that tracks the asking price, estimated selling price, and actual selling price, of two houses (in hundreds of thousands so 600 = 600K)

$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 500 \\ 505 \\ 455 \end{bmatrix}, v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 600 \\ 675 \\ 655 \end{bmatrix}$

What would the cross product mean in this context? a vector orthogonal to both these vectors provides no useful information? I think the dot product may be more useful, as you can see how much one vector is strechted by he other, and thus how much the price of one house affects the price of the other.

Comment: The cross product of houses is evidently a skyscraper

Comment: In all seriousness, the cross product doesn't exist in two dimensions.

Comment: edited the question to include another dimension

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is in fact not possible to find a vector which is orthogonal to both of those vectors. This should give you a clue as to the problem of cross products in a 2 dimensional vector space.

It turns out that the cross product as a notion works specifically in 3 dimensions, and 7. There is some more information here: [Cross Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

In this specific situation the dot product is also not particularly useful. The dot product is the product of the asking price plus the product of the selling price. It is possible that some matrices might have an interesting meaning in this context as to how they transform the space. However, the dot product doesn't seem to.

In general, it isn't always the case that vector space properties will always translate well to any application. But you can always leverage them if it seems like it may be useful.